Multiline zsh Completions
After much struggling, I have finally wrangled the zsh completion commands (_describe and _arguments) into doing what I want, which is to autocomplete some commonly used curl commands for me.  However, I would like to format the autocompletion for -d (JSON data) over multiple lines.
Desired behavior:
$ curl https://example.com -d<TAB>
$ {
$     ...json option 1...
$ }
$ {
$     ...json option 2...
$ }

Is this possible?  How should I approach it?

This is more like trying to generate arguments, rather than recognize known arguments. I would suggest writing a shell function to abstract this instead.
